# Bootstrap css is not working when using carousel

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

So basically it looks like my carousel does not have any styling whatsoever. I copied the exact code from ng-bootstrap carousel example but mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOCde.png) when running.

This is ngbootstraps
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQFFq.png).

Steps I did before:

I installed @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap, then I added bootsrap to my css and after that I imported ngModule and added it to my modules.

Any ideas why this does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my opinion, you added bootstrap incorrectly. When you are implementing bootstrap 5 to your html  besides adding this in :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You also have to add this right before body closing tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This script basically makes interactive elements possible without using js. Here is a link to doccumentation if you want to learn more:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/
Lemme know if this helped

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seemed that I had used bootstrap version 4.5.3 instead of 5.2.0...